# How can I tell when a function is accessing a local or external variable?

Tags: c, algorithm

I am currently attempting to understand this code I came across a C certification test. The correct output of the code is 12, 13, 13.
I tried printing out the values, before it calls the 3 final outputs and i noticed the reason being is that there's a scope difference between the external x declared at the top and the one inside the function. My question is, how do I know which of those functions are accessing which object throughout the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int x; 
int modifyvalue() 
{ 
    return(x+=10); 
}
int changevalue(int x) 
{ 
    return(x+=1); 
}


int main(){
    int x=10; 
    x++; 
    printf("[1] %d \n\n", x);  
    changevalue(x); 
    printf("[2] %d \n\n", x);
    x++;
    printf("[3] %d \n\n", x); 
    modifyvalue(); 
    printf("First output:%d \n\n\n",x);
    x++; 
    changevalue(x); 
    printf("Second output:%d \n\n\n",x); 
    modifyvalue(); 
    printf("Third output:%dn \n\n\n",x);
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you get a book (online or otherwise) on C++ and study the scoping rules. An alternative way of figuring this out is using a debugger and go through the code step by step, that's a good way to get insight into what is going on. Btw `changevalue` increments a copy of x and the return value is ignored.

Comment: There are three `x`s in your code - a global variable, local variable in `main`, and a parameter of `changevalue`. You simply just need to distinguish between which one is used at particular lines of code. Read some good book about C/C++, every one intended for beginners covers this elementary topic.

Comment: @stijn the debugger does not identify the context

Comment: @JohnJones it might not hand it to you on a plate, but it's all there and should be enough to figure it out (which is the idea here, to be able to learn it). Any proper debugger should be able to show you simultaneously the values of `x` in local scope and the global `::x` and allow you to switch between stack frames and hence get to see the value (and addresses) of all 3 x's used here.

Comment: this function: `modifyvalue()` is the only place where the global 'x' is accessed in all other places, a local 'x' is accessed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always take the variable from nearest scope.
Whenever the `printf("...", x)` is called, it takes the `x` from the function `main()`.

The function `modifyvalue()` always operates on the `x` outside of all functions.

The function `changevalue(int x)` always operates on the parameter `x` - which is a copy of the variable passed in.

So in your case, both functions essentially do nothing to the `x` in `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

The rule is simple, in every { ... } (block) you can reference either a variable that is define in that block or any "parent" of it. For example in your code:

- modifyvalue: no x, x is in parent, "global"
- changevalue: x is a parameter, increment **the parameter**, change not reflected on the caller (because the parameter is a copy)
- main: x is local

Notice that you are printing always "the main's x" that is incremented only in the main.
As noted by @Jens, the parent scope in C is called enclosing block and the global scope is called program scope (file scope + external)

Comment: Terminology hint: "parent" in C is called *enclosing block*; "global" is called *file scope* (and usually with *external linkage*).